# How to generate string based on Pattern

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I have a case where I have to generate transaction number based on specific pattern
The pattern is following:

> MA 0000000/dd/mm/YYYY/00000

where first zeros are random numbers then current date and last zeros should be incremental

> (00001... 00010... 00100... 00578)

Could you please provide correct way to implement this case.

Comment: _Incremental_ means you are storing them in database or where?

Comment: First Part is sample I am just using random chars and generating first part based on that but the problem for me is that this should be sample method which only last zero part as an parameter and increase it by 1 so this method should look something like this

and yeas I am storing this data in database, but on app start last inserted item is selected and kept inside app memory till program terminates so I do not have to read it every time I want to insert record in DB insert
GetApplyNumber(0007) which then returns MA 5447785/27/9/2012/0008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static class Generator
{
    static int current = 0;
    static Random rand = new Random();

    public static string NextId()
    {
        return string.Format("MA {0:0000000}/{1}/{2:00000}", 
          rand.Next() % 100000,
          DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
          current++ );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really good solution, but How should I supply current LastID to incrementation it?

Comment: you probably shouldn't, but if you really want to, my solution below allows you to supply the previous id

Comment: Thank u very much I really need to supply it because this process is not running all the time So after restart I need to know from which to continue. I maker your code as answered

Comment: if you need to persist the last incremental part of the id (current in the code above), then you should change the implementation to make it available from outside the class, read it when you close the app and set it when you start the app.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public string NextId(int lastCount)
    {
        var rand = new Random();

        return string.Format("MA{0:0000000}/{1}/{2:00000}", 
            rand.Next(9999999),
            DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            lastCount + 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber = rand.Next(100000000);
int counter = 1;
string str = "MA" + randomNumber.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("/dd/MM/yyyy/") + counter.ToString("X4");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Probably you are concerned about two things:
DateTime format: you may use: `DateTime.Now.ToString("/dd/MM/yyyy/")`

and

Padding leading zeros to a number, you may use:

`counter.ToString("X4")`

Also see: [How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();
string random = rand.Next(10000000).ToString("D7");
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string increment = inc.ToString("D5");
String.Format("MA {0}/{1}/{2}", random, date, increment);
```

Where inc is the incremental number. You should know this, or otherwise find out what the next number should be.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("MA "+(new Random()).Next(0,100).ToString("D7")+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")+ i.ToString("D5"));
}
```

Where `Next()` generates random number between 0 and 100

`i.ToString("D5")` will give you number in 00001.. format